# Assigning custom extension as static resource to Color property

Tags: wpf, xaml

I created an extension that takes a color value and modifies the HSL values by the specified amount. Here is the relevant part of the extension.

```java
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(Color))]
internal class RelativeColor : MarkupExtension
{
    public Color BaseColor { get; set; }
    public float H { get; set; }
    public float S { get; set; }
    public float L { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ColorHSL c = RGBtoHSL(BaseColor);
        c.H *= H == 0f ? 1f : H;
        c.L *= L == 0f ? 1f : L;
        c.S *= S == 0f ? 1f : S;
        return HSLtoRGB(c);         //Returns Color object
    }

    // Additional methods that converts between HSL and RGB
}
```

Here is the XAML I put in the App.xaml

```xml
<Style.Resources>
    <Extensions:RelativeColor x:Key="ButtonBackgroundColor" BaseColor="{StaticResource WorkspaceBackground}" L="1.18"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackground" Color="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorder" Color="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonHoverBorder" Color="#B2B2B2" />
 </Style.Resources>
```

Now, during runtime everything is fine, there are no errors. However, during design time the XAML editor throws this error:

```
Error   1   An object of the type "X.Extensions.RelativeColor" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.Media.Color".  c:\...\app.xaml 18  62
```

This points to the first two SolidColorBrush lines in the xaml. Any ideas on how to fix this, and get the designer to update the preview properly?

Comment: The designer is crap, i doubt that there is much you can do, though i do not have much experience with it as i refuse to use it these days...

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. Thanks any ways.

Comment: Markup extensions apparently only work when directly set as property values.